# how to stop onclick from firing twice using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
function save_team()
{
      $('#saveBtn').unbind('click');

      $.ajax(
      {        
        type: "POST",
        url: "save.php",
        data: { team_Array : t_pls },

          success: function(data) {
              $('#msg').text(data);
          }
      });    
}

<input type="submit" value="SAVE" id="saveBtn" onclick="save_team()">
```

I searched, found some solutions, but they dont work. how to prevent SAVE button/onclick event from firing twice?? i'm trying to save team of 10 players in mysql. If team is same and onclick event occurs nothing should happen. 
Someone suggested me to do this in the PHP script (in my case save.php). But i couldn't think of perfect solution.

I think i have to do this using php. When team doesnt change, onclick event should be disabled and when team does change ajax call should be made and team should be saved in DB.
So, one() call or disable attr. wont help here. pls suggest some php script help.

Comment: You could disable the button once it has been clicked

Comment: Bind the handler with [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) so that it will only fire once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple solution is to disable the button and enable it on callback.

```
$('#saveBtn').attr('disabled','disabled')
```

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="SAVE" id="saveBtn" onclick="save_team()">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#saveBtn').attr('disabled','disabled')
```

Disable button and enable when response comes back from ajax.

Answer (score 1):

for disable the button.

```
$('#Btn').attr('disabled',true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to disable the button once it is clicked for the first time. Before the ajax call. We have to careful to enable the button on success as well on error. You can use the complete of AJAX call also to enable the button.

```
           {
                   $('#btnId').attr("disabled", true);
                  // make the AJAX call..
                  $('#btnId').attr("disabled", false);
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery one  :

```
$( "#saveBtn" ).one( "click", function() {
   save_team();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest doing three things. Firstly disabled the button once it has been clicked.

```
$('#saveBtn').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

secondly bind the click handler using one()

```
$("#saveBtn").one('click', save_team);
```

Thirdly, this is putting business logic in your UI so if it has to be there then the checks should be duplicated in your php on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery one method

```
$('#saveBtn').one('click', save_team)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must cancel the automatic form submission returning `false` in your function and returning it in your `onclick` attribute value too:

```
function save_team()
{
    //$('#saveBtn').unbind('click');    I think this line is not needed anymore
    $.ajax(
    {        
        type: "POST",
        url: "save.php",
        data: { team_Array : t_pls },

        success: function(data) {
            $('#msg').text(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

<input type="submit" value="SAVE" id="saveBtn" onclick="return save_team()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button and on success or error re enable it.